# QuantileTransformer in PySpark

Tags: pyspark, scikit-learn, apache-spark-ml

How to implement the Scikit learn QuantileTransformer in PySpark? Due to the size of my data set (~68 million rows w/ 100+ columns), I am forced to attempt this in PySpark rather than converting it into Pandas. I am on PySpark 2.4.

I've seen PySpark has scalers such as StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler, etc. But I would like to use an equivalent of QuantileTransformer. Is there anything off the shelf that exists for this purpose?